# Bootstrap row doesn't work upon upgrading bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm upgrading a website from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 4. For some reason, the footer grid row stopped working. It went from this: [image]

To this: [image]

I'm not sure what happened. This is the code for that section. It has all the quotes because it is speedscript rendering html (Yes, it is that old)
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Migrating from Bootstrap 2.x to 4.x will require you to review the migration documentation. For example, the `col-xs-*` class no longer exists so in your above screenshot it would be ignored and the smallest honored size would now be `col-sm-6`.  If you want a 12-wide column at the smallest breakpoint you need to use `col-12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert said, `Bootstrap 4.x` is a major rewrite of the entire project. The most notable changes are summarized here @ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/.

Replacing `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">` with `<div class="col-6 col-md-3">` should be working. But once again, you might want to hire someone to do the transition as this might affect more than what just meets the eyes.

---

### Bootstrap 5.x is coming!

Furthermore, `Bootrap 5.x` is coming out soon and is currently in alpha https://v5.getbootstrap.com/, with major changes, one of them being the drop of jQuery. You might want to hold on before jumping to `Bootstrap 4.x` and instead jumping straight to `Bootstrap 5.x` or maybe get a new website?

> Bootstrap no longer depends on jQuery and we’ve dropped support for
> Internet Explorer. We’re sharpening our focus on building tools that
> are more future-friendly, and while we’re not fully there yet, the
> promise of CSS variables, faster JavaScript, fewer dependencies, and
> better APIs certainly feel right to us.
>
> Before you jump to updating, please remember v5 is now in
> alpha—breaking changes will continue to occur until our first beta. We
> haven’t finished adding or removing everything, so check for open
> issues and pull requests as you have questions or feedback.

Source @ https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/06/16/bootstrap-5-alpha/

---

### Additional information

Some great people already thaught of making your life easier, you can take a look at the migration tools from the Bootly team here:

`Bootstrap 2.x` -> `Bootstrap 3.x` @ http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/v3

`Bootstrap 3.x` -> `Bootstrap 4.x` @ http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

Comment: If this answered your question d'ont forget to use to checkmark to accept the answer